# how to get text from readonly value in python selenium module

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
input type="text" id="capt_cnt" readonly="" value="0000"
```

At random, the four numbers vary for each refresh.

I want to extract the text of this element from the site, but I don't know how. It is possible to copy and paste by hand.

I tried `get_attribute`, `get.text`, `class`, `xpath`, `id`, ... Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "capt_cnt")))
print(element.get_attribute("value"))
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't fully understand but it works. Thank you.

Comment: What this answer provides is a solution to the problem, with including some optimizations and not much explanation. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76930465/2648551), which provides some text in addition to the source code. You can hopefully benefit from both answers. The full blown example with information from me and the optimizations from this answer (waiting until the elements are rendered/visible in the browser). Both answers have `get_attribute("value")` after getting the element which have `capt_cnt` as an id. If both answers helped, please upvote both and accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_attribute`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) is the right approach. But you need to find the `<input>` element first, which contains the wanted attribute `value`. This can be done by [`find_element()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element). The default is to search for an `id` and you have an id field, so it is pretty straight forward.

Here is a full blown example (I don't have Chrome installed, but I assume it will work the same way with Firefox):

My folder looks like this:

```bash
.
├── geckodriver
├── index.html
└── text_extract.py
```

*(The geckodriver is downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and the executable of my Firefox can be found under `/usr/bin/firefox` (Linux system))*

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test_div">
        <label for="capt_cnt"></label>
        <input type="text" id="capt_cnt" readonly="" value="0000">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**text_extract.py**

```py
from pathlib import Path

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

# Setup
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
service = Service(str(Path.cwd() / "geckodriver"))
local_file = (Path.cwd() / "index.html").as_uri()

# Start Webbrowser
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

# Get index.html
driver.get(local_file)

# Find <input> element by its id "capt_cnt" (finding by id is default)
input_field = driver.find_element(value="capt_cnt")

# Extract the content of the field "value"
wanted_value = input_field.get_attribute("value")

driver.quit()

print(wanted_value)  # outputs "0000" the content of the input value field
assert wanted_value == "0000"  # also proofed by assert statement
```

The imports and setups have to be adapted of course when using other browser drivers. Optimizations can be done by e.g. waiting for the elements to show up like [Shawn already demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76930099/2648551).